# How to create group on openfire and then add member on group using URL?

Tags: php

I want to create group on open fire and then add member on that group using URL.

I have create the user on open fire by using this URL:

http://myhostname:port/plugins/userService/userservice?type=add&secret=mysecretkey&username=$username&password=$password&name=$name&email=$email

Please help me to create group and add users on that group and I have used this URL to create group:

```
http://myhostname:port/plugins/userService/userservice?type=add&secret=mysecretkey&name='spalchat'&description='parent'
```

But, it throws an exception: `<error>IllegalArgumentException</error>`

Answer (score -1):

Try using a php [library](http://www.planetxmpp.com/libraries/)  for xmpp :

1. [Eiffel](https://github.com/jocelyn/bricabrac/wiki/Eiffel-XMPP)
2. [xmpphp](http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/)
3. [Lightr](http://code.google.com/p/lightr/)
4. [JAXL](http://code.google.com/p/jaxl/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I mean I want to understand, Why the - 1??